# ForecastCategoryName Field Missing in Opportunity Spring 2020

Tags: community

Is anyone missing ForecastCategoryName Field in SFDC Sanboxes on Opportunities after Spring 2020 release?

I don't even see the option of re-enabling forecasting in sandbox in this release.

Also, since this field is referred in Financial Force, its breaking whole of our sandbox. Any idea how to proceed with the debugging ?